# A function about prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, terminology

Is there a function defined like this? $p(x)=1$ if $x$ is a prime, $p(x)=0$ if $x$ isn't a prime. If there is, what is the symbol of it?

Comment: The function will be very discontinuous.

Comment: No, there is no standard symbol, and lots of ad hoc ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [characteristic function of primes](http://oeis.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_of_prime_numbers):

$$
    \chi_{\rm prime}(n) \equiv \pi(n) - \pi(n-1) \, 
$$
where $\pi(n) \, $is the prime counting function.

I forgot where but I also have seen some calling it $\nu(n)$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason that this is better than the opposite?

$$\pi(n)=\sum \chi_{\text {prime}}(i)$$

Comment: @Sabyasachi it might depend on your definition of "better"...or your problem...